# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'number_gag' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

En mi model Piece(modelo principal), tengo una relacion HasOne con model Gag y Model Program.

**En la seccion mordaza tengo un autocompletado mediante ajax desde donde se debe seleccionar un numero de mordazas para autocompletar los campos.**

[image: piece_gag]

En este caso a **modo de prueba modifique solamente el campo diametro** como se puede ver en la imagen, he intente actualizar y recibo el siguiente error:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'number_gag' cannot be null (SQL: update `gags` set `number_gag` = , `diameter` = 430, `updated_at` = 2020-02-24 10:15:09 where `id` = 1)",

**el error desaparece si yo eligo desde el select otro numero de mordaza, entonces en este caso se guarda sin problemas.**

lo cual lo que pretendo es que **me permita modificar algunos campos de la seccion mordaza, sin tener que selecionar otro numero de mordaza**

si en mi metodo store puedo guardar la informacion de esta manera

metodo store:

```
                $gag     = Gag::create($request->all());
                $program = Program::create($request->all()); 

                $piece = $program->piece()->create([
                    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
                    'code'         => $request['code'],
                    'time'         => $request['time'],
                    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],
                    'gag_id'       => $gag->id
                ]);
```

En mi metodo update estoy tratando de guardar la  informacion a actualizar de la siguiente manera:

metodo update:

```
                $piece  = Piece::with('tools','gag')->findOrFail($id);   

                $gag = $piece->gag()->update($request->all());
                $program = $piece->program()->update($request->all());

                $piece->update($request->all());
```

De que manera puedo resolver este problema?

Este es mi modelo pieza:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Piece extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'program_id', 'gag_id', 'denomination', 'code', 'part_piece', 'time', 'observation'
    ];    

    public function program()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Program::class);
    }  

    public function gag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Gag::class);
    } 

    public function tools() 
    {        
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tool::class)->withTimestamps();
    }   

}
```

model Gag:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gag extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'number_gag','diameter','type_gag','category_gag'
    ];

    public function piece()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Piece::class);
    }    
}
```

Formulario (seccion mordaza):

```
 {!! Form::model($piece, [
        'route' => $piece->exists ? ['admin.pieces.update', $piece->id] : 'admin.pieces.store',   
        'method' => $piece->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
    ]) !!}  
     <div class="form-group">                    
                    <label>Mordaza N°</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-industry"></i>
                        </div>               
                        <select name="number_gag" id="number_gag" class="form-control select2" {{{$enable}}}>
                            <option value=""></option>
                                @foreach ($gags as $gag)                                  
                                    <option value="{{ $gag->id }}"                           
                                        {{ old('number_gag', $piece->gag_id) == $gag->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                                        {{ $gag->number_gag }}
                                    </option>                     
                                @endforeach  
                        </select>
                    </div>                                    
                </div>               

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('diameter', 'Diametro') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </div>                                 
                        {!! Form::text('diameter', $piece->gag['diameter'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'diameter', 'placeholder' => 'Diametro de mordaza']) !!}                              
                    </div>
                </div>   

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('type_gag', 'Tipo') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </div>        
                        {!! Form::select('type_gag', $type_gag, $piece->gag['type_gag'], ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'type_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Tipo de mordaza']) !!}                     
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group">                    
                    {!! Form::label('category_gag', 'Categoria') !!}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                        </div>                                     
                        {!! Form::select('category_gag', $category_gag, $piece->gag['category_gag'], ['class' => 'form-control select2', 'id' => 'category_gag', 'placeholder' => 'Categoria de mordaza']) !!}                            
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

realizando un  dd($request->all()); justo aca:

```
   dd($request->all());
                $gag = $piece->gag()->update($request->all());            
                $program = $piece->program()->update($request->all());

                $piece = $gag->piece()->update([
                    'denomination' => $request['denomination'],
                    'code'         => $request['code'],
                    'time'         => $request['time'],
                    'part_piece'   => $request['part_piece'],
                    'gag_id'       => $request['number_gag']
                ]);
```

obtengo lo siguiente:

```
array:15 [
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "3c3FCoNm2yLdnyRWJ4pUBaKLMQixAiLpLUjH689F"
  "denomination" => "sint"
  "code" => "8888-8888-8/8"
  "part_piece" => "2"
  "addmore" => array:1 [
    0 => array:6 [
      "insert_id" => "1"
      "tool_id" => "1"
      "position" => "3"
      "code_tool" => "81800"
      "code_insert" => "76377-8991"
      "quality" => "1863"
    ]
  ]
  "name_program" => "8888-8888-8/8"
  "number_program" => "4554"
  "part_program" => "2"
  "number_gag" => null
  "diameter" => "120"
  "type_gag" => "EXTERIOR"
  "category_gag" => "CON TOPE"
  "time" => "1:22:47"
  "observation" => null
]
```

la pieza que estoy tratando de editar es la siguiente:

[image: edit_update]

como se puede ver en la imagen esta pieza tiene registrada como numero de mordaza a numero:68 pero en la con dd() en el campo gag_id= null

mi metodo edit: 'gags' => Gag::all(),  con esto traigo a todas las mordazas que existen en mi db

```
 public function edit($id)
    {        
        $piece  = Piece::with('gag')->findOrFail($id); 

        // $this->authorize('update', $piece);  

        return view('admin.pieces.partials.form', [         

            'part_piece'    => Piece::pluck('part_piece', 'part_piece'), 
            'denomination'  => Piece::pluck('denomination', 'denomination'), 

            'gags'          => Gag::all(),          
            'number_gag'    => Gag::pluck('number_gag', 'number_gag'),         
            'type_gag'      => Gag::pluck('type_gag', 'type_gag'),           
            'category_gag'  => Gag::pluck('category_gag', 'category_gag'), 

            'part_program'  => Program::pluck('part_program', 'part_program'),                      
            'piece'         => $piece
        ]);  
    }
```

**ACTUALIZADO 2**

Cree una nueva pieza en este caso para la sección de mordaza en numero de mordaza seleccione a la que tiene numero 68, (en el select seleccione a la n° 68), al darle actualizar se actualiza pero para este caso me guardo el id de donde se encuentra la numero 68 se entiende? ver imagen

[image: tabla gags]

osea que me esta guardando el id desde donde se encuentra la mordaza que selecciono.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104864/discussion-on-question-by-rodrigo-ruiz-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-colu).